# Speed up SQLite select with Python and wx.ListCtrl

Tags: python, sqlite, select, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm using `Python 2.7.5+` on Kubuntu `13.10` with `wx 2.8.12.1`.

**I have not big database (about 3150 rows)** where I have only a single table of employees (firstname, lastname, address, phone, email). In my application I store them in `SQLite` database and use `wx.ListCtrl` to show rows to user.

However, loading such database to `wx.ListCtrl` takes ages (more than about 10 seconds I think). **The question is: is it possible to improve the select speed?**

Firstly, in my Python code, I create a table:

```
def createEmployeesTable(self):
        connection = sqlite.connect(self.dbname)
        try:
            with connection:
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                sql = '''\
                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employees (
                        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                        FIRSTNAME TEXT,
                        LASTNAME TEXT,
                        EMAIL TEXT,
                        ADDRESS TEXT,
                        PHONE TEXT)
                '''
                cursor.execute(sql)
        finally:
            connection.close()
```

Then, I insert some employees' data and finally do the select to show data in a pop-up window with `wx.ListCtrl` on it:

```
def getAllEmployees(self):
        employees = []
        connection = sqlite.connect(self.dbname)
        try:
            with connection:
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, email, phone, address FROM Employees"
                cursor.execute(sql)
                for (firstname, lastname, email, phone, address, ) in cursor:
                    employees.append(Employee(firstname, lastname, email, phone, address))
        finally:
            connection.close()
        return employees
```

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use the virtual version of `wx.ListCtrl`. It's mentioned in the [documentation](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/ListCtrl.html) as follows:

*A special case of report view quite different from the other modes of the list control is a virtual control in which the items data (including text, images and attributes) is managed by the main program and is requested by the control itself only when needed which allows to have controls with millions of items without consuming much memory.*

There don't seem to be much in the way of examples, but I did find tthe following:

- https://wiki.wxpython.org/ListControls
- http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Virtual-ListCtrl-An-example-with-a-question-td5716497.html

There's also a complete example in the wxPython demo that has almost 1,000,000 items in it, so you should definitely check that out.

Comment: Thanks, will check this out! :)

Comment: This is a useful answer; however, the link mentioned in the second sentence no longer seems to be available. https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ListCtrl.html might be its replacement.